# Any ASP.NET (WebForm) apps which have good unit tests (CodePlex or anywhere)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit, webforms

I am looking for any ASP.NET (WebForms & C#) app which has some good unit tests in its solution. Good meaning testing different kinds of edge cases and does a good code coverage. Any app on CodePlex, GitHub or anywhere is fine.

This is for educational purposes so I prefer smaller apps than large ones.
Any recommendations?

**Clarification:**

While the app is WebForms, the unit tests I am interested is more on business logic, not the UI. Yes any .NET app can do but if it is WebForms with some UI testing, the better.

Comment: It's probably somewhat hard to come by testable straight WebForms, but you may have more luck with the [MVP pattern](http://webformsmvp.codeplex.com/releases/view/63338).  It still uses WebForms but in a slightly different way.

Comment: @ROMAN: don't believe myths. It's as easy to unit test Web Forms code as it is to unit test MVC code. Just don't permit the code to be checked in with any business logic in the presentation layer, and then unit test the business logic.

Comment: @John: Fair enough, you can apply good practices to any kind of code (including WebForms).  Though there's nothing in the framework that would guide you towards writing more testable code.

Comment: @ROMAN: a good programmer doesn't need to be "guided" to doing a good job.

Comment: @John: I feel like that would only be true within a given domain.  Any time you switch, not all of the skills would be directly transferable so it's helpful to have a framework guides you towards a better approach.

Comment: @ROMAN: Either that, or else competent senior developers who don't permit garbage code to be checked in.

Answer (score 2):

[ScrewTurn wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/Download.ashx) is open-source, version 3.x is coded in C# and ASP.NET 3.5, and the source comes bundled with tests for the components.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that unit tests in the business logic layer are not sufficient for any web application, no matter what the framework used.

The best policy is to have a serious "smoke test", perhaps kept in an Excel workbook, where you exercise every known possible set of inputs and actions and are able to determine that "everything works" whenever you do a new deployment.

Unit tests are valuable, but they cannot reproduce the behavior of an application in production.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what kinds of bugs you write into your code. If your business logic and maybe even database logic is thoroughly unit tested, then you do not have any bugs there. That leaves bugs in your presentation code, which can be prevented by automated UI testing and even more so, by code review.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Don't know exactly if it's what you wanted :) It is ASP.NET with MVP pattern implemented and it has some test coverage - [.NET Framework 3.5 Bundle](http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVP_landing_page)

Answer (score 0):

I've just finish a web e-commerce site. 
For the business logic I create a separate dll, and I use NUnit to test it. Nunit is simple to use, it's simple (and fast) to launch with a .bat file and it is possible to use a graphic interface.

In the web site, I use NLOG for logging user action. In this case the best way (after YOU test it for a while) is to give your site to some final customer, and watch the log file every time there is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for coding examples to learn unit testing but

Foundations of Programming - Building Better Software By Karl Seguin

is a good book to help guide you through the process of unit testing a mocking. It's only 79 pages long and should get you up and running quickly.

http://openmymind.net/FoundationsOfProgramming.pdf