# Testing two dependent classes in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependencies, moq

The problem I want to solve is, how to test two dependent classes in C#. For testing I'm using NUnit and Moq.

Let's say I have a custom collection which autonumerates its items. Values inside collection must be kept in its original order, so that's the reason why it has to be autonumerated. Following code shows the most simple example of mentioned classes:

```
public interface ICustomItem
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ICustomCollection<ICustomItem> ParentCollection { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomCollection<T> where T : ICustomItem
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    void Add(T t);
    // And more of course...
}

public class CustomCollection<T> : ICustomCollection<T> where T : ICustomItem
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        // Some logic here...
        t.Id = Items.Count(); // Generate Id
    }
}
```

When adding item to collection, a new Id is generated and assigned to CustomItem. Mechanism of autonumerating should be included also in other methods, such as Remove(), but for this question I've left Add method only.

The question is, how to test if autonumerates works correctly? When the mock is passed as a param, it is not modified inside the class. Should I test the class with simple instance of created-for-tests CustomItem class?

**tl;dr**

In other words, I want to be able to modify a mock inside a class.

Comment: Why you can't use Mock<ICustomItem>? You could create mock with SetupSet on Id property.

Comment: @msergey: But how to setup mock id setter to check if it is modified inside Add() method correctly? Can you provide an example?

Comment: are you able to check it after Add()? Hence, you add item to collection and check that Id was set correctly **after** running Add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the class in the test just as you would use it from the production code. This will give you the most usable test in the sense that you are free to refactor the code inside the classes without breaking or even changing a test. The test will also serve as an example on how to use the class.

To start out I would not use Moq, but rather use a short `MockCustomItem` class that you implement just for the test.

Then use add some values and assert that result is what you expected. Make it a habit to only use one assert in each test like below.

```
[TestFixture]
public class GivenCustomCollectionWithTwoElements
{
    private CustomCollection<MockCustomItem> _customCollection;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _customCollection = new CustomCollection<MockCustomItem>();

        _customCollection.Add(new MockCustomItem());
        _customCollection.Add(new MockCustomItem()); 
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckLength()
    {
        Assert.That(_customCollection.Items, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckFirstItemId()
    {
        Assert.That(_customCollection.Items.ElementAt(0).Id, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }

    [Test]
    public void CheckSecondItemId()
    {
        Assert.That(_customCollection.Items.ElementAt(1).Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    private class MockCustomItem : ICustomItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICustomCollection<ICustomItem> ParentCollection { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Once you get the hang of this, you can also use Moq to create more concise tests with less boilerplate code. In this case NUnit parameterizedtest cases could also be used.

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests you shall only test the unit you are testing right now. So I wold say that you shall mock/fake the ICustomItem and send it in and then looks if the faked object get the Id you expect.

Read my answer here for further info about the same topic [Any ASP.NET (WebForm) apps which have good unit tests (CodePlex or anywhere)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406012/any-asp-net-webform-apps-which-have-good-unit-tests-codeplex-or-anywhere/6678524#6678524)

I use FakeItEasy as mock/fake-framework but I guess moq would look pretty similar, here is my code for it

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomCollectionTests{

    [Test]
    public void Add_AddTwoItems_ItemsGetsConsecutiveIds() {
        var customItem1 = A.Fake<ICustomItem>();
        var customItem2 = A.Fake<ICustomItem>();
        var cutomCollection = new CustomCollection<ICustomItem>();
        cutomCollection.Add(customItem1);
        cutomCollection.Add(customItem2);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, customItem1.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, customItem2.Id);
    }
}


public interface ICustomItem {
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomCollection<T> where T : ICustomItem {
    void Add(T t);
}

public class CustomCollection<T> : ICustomCollection<T> where T : ICustomItem {
    public List<T> innerList = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T t) {
        // Some logic here...
        innerList.Add(t);
        t.Id = innerList.Count(); // Generate Id
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Removed non tested MOQ-example that seemed to be not working.

Comment: Your Moq code is wrong: first you have to use customItem#.Object, second, you cannot modify a mock inside Add() method.

Comment: Ah, FakeItEasy seems to handle this a bit easier then ;) I remove the MOQ code example again then.

Comment: Check out this link where Osherove explains why one assert per test is important: http://osherove.com/blog/2006/10/3/avoid-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test-revisited.html

Comment: That is true, you shall strive to just have one assert per test, but if you consider the context of that text you will realize that the most important thing in a unit test is that you test one thing which I am still doing in my test (read the method name that clearly describe what I am testing). The reason why I have two asserts here is because the code is dependent on a previous call, which can imply a weakness in the tested code. In this case the CustomCollection is actually a kind of statemachine which you shall try to avoid.

Comment: Blaming the system under test is no reason to write problematic tests - Do the best of the situation or improve the production code! Or in this case - Give a hint about how to improve it.

Comment: But, if you really want one assert just for the case of it (which isn't very pragmatic and not as clear in my option ;)) you can remove the assets to Assert.AreEqual(customItem1.Id, customItem2.Id + 1);

Comment: I would probably move the generation of the Id to another class rather than to have it in the collection. If you read the single responsibility principle you will find out that one class shall have one responsibility. Your collection both store ICustomItems but also modifies them.

Comment: I do not exactly now what you are trying to are trying to achieve. But I would consider first add the ICustomItem to the collection and then (maybe depending on the index returned from the collection) generate the Id for the added ICustomItem, maybe in a CustomerItemFactory or similar.

Comment: Or even better, try to generate the Id before adding it and make the CustomItem object immutable, but that depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you tough, and since I do not know more about your code than what is written in the question I can not say IF there is a weakness, only that it CAN imply in a weakness ;)

Comment: @Martin Odhelius: After creating CustomerItemFactory, I will also have to check if CustomItem got proper Id. And the question raises again: Two classes, dependencies between them - how to test it?

Comment: To begin with, what exactly is the logic you are using for generating the Id? Is it only the index of the collection it is added to? If you create two different collections, and add the same ICustomItem to both of them? If you for example have factory you can let the Facotory keep track of the Id:s alone, no other class shall be able to modify or change the Id but the factory. If you still need to create an Id inside another class, consider to use the strategy pattern and let the strategy keep track of the Id creation.

Comment: You shall not have cross dependencies in your code, then you have design flaws. If you have dependencies you shall have one way dependencies and inject our dependencies into the depending object. Unit tests is a great way to find such design flaws, that is why it is so good to write tests for your code. It is nothing wrong to find weaknesses in your code while your write tests for it, that is one of the point with unit testing.

Comment: If you want to know more about dependency injection etc. you can start to study the SOLID principles by Robert C Martin (also called Uncle Bob). He probably explains this much better than me ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that vidstige and ventr1s where two different people ;) I thought I was speaking to the same person all the time... my bad. sorry ;) All that I said still apply though

Answer (score 0):

You're right in the fact that the mock isn't modified. But you should be able to verify the mock after calling the add method like this:

```
mock.VerifySet(x => x.Id = 42);
```

Remember to set something in the Items property before calling Add. That something should return 42, when asking for the Count(). That could be a mock as well.

Comment: Sorry. Just realized that you are using the Count() extension method on IEnumerable<T> and not the Count property available on List and other collection types. Count() is a static method (extension method) and therefore can't be mocked :(

Comment: You don't need to use a mock for items though. Just do this:

Comment: var col = new CustomCollection<ICustomItem>();
    col.Items = new List<ICustomItem>(new Mock<ICustomItem>().Object)

Comment: Dough. You can't make newlines :) With the above list set on your collection, the Count() method will return 1.